# PHP OOP problem

Tags: php, oop

I have classes `Video` and `Audio`, which extend class `Popular`

In class, Video & Audio is a function of "public static function parsing ()" are different in themselves

So, as I can from the class of "Popular" address to the class that calls?
That is in a class of "Popular" is a function of "getSong" which has a function call "parsing ()", but here's how to call this function from the class that turns ..
Hopefully clearly explained ..
Kind of like the opposite function of need "parent"

```
class Video extends Popular {

    public static function parsing()
    {
        return 'Videooooooooooooo';
        .....
    }

    public static fuinction tratata()
    {
    ....
    }

}

class Audio extends Popular {

    public static function parsing()
    {
       .............
        return 'Audio';
        .....
    }

    public static fuinction tratata()
    {
    ....
    }

}

class Popular {

    public static function getSong()
    {
        $class = '???????';//Video or Audio???
        $class::parsing();// ???
    }

}
```

Sorry for bad english.. used google traslate

Comment: This may be an issue of late static bindings. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: I haven't a clue what's going on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for this behavior.

Put the `parsing` function in the `Popular` class, so that `Audio` and `Video` inherit it. Then your `getSong` just looks like this.

EDIT: `self` keyword is bound to the class in which the function is defined. So the below is wrong. The correct answer is to use the `static` keyword instead - IF you are using PHP 5.3.0 or later.

```
public static function getSong()
{
    static::parsing();
}
```

### below is wrong

---

```
public static function getSong()
{
    self::parsing();
}
```

But really, getSong is no longer needed. When a base class implementation is called on a child class, `self` still refers to the child class, so the correct `parsing` function will be called automatically.

Did I understand your question correctly?

Also to everyone else: if I'm wrong about this behavior, then shame on me and I need to go back to school. I haven't used this behavior in a while so I may be rusty.

Comment: Actually, this PHP bug report - http://bugs.php.net/30934 - says I'm wrong. But also that PHP is being stupid here. Damn you PHP.

Answer (score 0):

@Tesserex probaly has the best answer.

Not sure whether this is what you mean, but to find out the class name of the current object:

You seem to be using these functions in static context. That makes things more difficult. As far as I know, the only way to find out in that case is PHP 5.3's [`get_called_class()`.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php)

Comment: All his method calls are static (dunno why) so I'm not sure he'd have a `$this` to check.  This looks like it might be a late-static-binding issue but the code is pretty confusing.